# Java Mail API host name

Tags: smtp, jakarta-mail, imap, mail-server

I have implemented IMAP server mail box and one valid user account on that mail box for receiving email and reading mail.
Now I want to send mail through that user account. After goggling  for some time , I found that we can't send mail using IMAP server.

So now the problem is I want to send mail using that mail account only. Is there any way?

Comment: You need an SMTP server, which you can set up with authentication to restrict to that account.

Comment: @Max I tried using gmail smtp server and used the account ,Which I have made using IMAP mail box,i.e. name@example.me and the account specific password. But I got Authentication Failed Exception. Any Idea how to do it